# Where to set AuthConfigConsts for the angular2-jwt?

Tags: angular, auth0, angular2-jwt

I'm using [angular2-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt#basic-configuration) for authentication. I need to change the default token name from `token` to `customer`.

I know I need to change `DEFAULT_TOKEN_NAME` property in `AuthConfigConsts`. But I'm not sure where and how should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when creating your factory that will be provided to the `NgModule`:

```
// Provider

/**
 * Factory for JWT Authentication.
 *
 * @param http
 * @param options
 * @returns {AuthHttp}
 */
export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig({
    tokenName: '<yourTokenName>',
  }), http, options);
}


// @NgModule provider:

{
  provide: AuthHttp,
  useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
  deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
},
```

[`AuthConfig`'s constructor](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/e61abf054c89bd3fa91c56c541e6b269d91dbf16/angular2-jwt.ts#L66) set's those properties using `Object.assign`.